# Eclipse's embedded Maven doesn't accept run-time arguments

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have configured *jar.version* as dynamic input to **pom.xml**

```
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>${jar.version}</version>
```

I tried to configure maven goal in eclipse's run configuration as

```
clean install -Djar.version=1.0.1
```

I also tried to add *jar.version=1.0.1* in parameter section of maven run configuration.
**But this parameter is not accessible by maven build process. Need help here.**

I am able to access it if i use external maven (and not eclipse's embedded one) then below command works well

```
mvn clean install -Djar.version=1.0.1
```

Comment: This way it will not in Eclipse cause this way it's not supported by Maven...If you are using Maven 3.5.0+ You can do it a little bit different see more details at https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html (I recommend to use the most recent Maven version 3.5.4...

Comment: I didnot find any issue when ran command through maven command prompt. In maven run configuration, there is option to add parameters, which should ideally work. But in my case its not working.

Comment: I know it simply that it does not work cause I've implemented the ci friendly part in Maven and I know you can't overwrite properties via command line...

Comment: @KrishnatMolawade, has this been solved for you meanwhile? 
I'm experiencing the same with a maven run configuration, the runtime parameters that I add do not arrive in the program, the `args` array comes in empty. 
Is there a bug in Maven? My environment is pretty new, Eclipse version: 2021-12 (4.22.0) with Eclipse.org - m2e, M2E Maven Integration for Eclipse Core 1.19.0.20211116-0804